# Minimum number of zeros of an equation have $3$rd derivative.

Tags: calculus

> Let $y=f(x)$ be thrice differentiable function  defined on $\mathbb{R}$ such that  $f(x)=0$ has at least $5$ distinct zeros? Then find minimum no. of zeros of $f(x)+6f'(x)+12f''(x)+8f'''(x)=0$ is

Try: $$f(x)=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)(x-e)$$ where $a<b<c<d<e$

But finding $f''(x)$ and $f'''(x)$ is very tough task. Could some help me to solve it Thanks

Comment: But $$f(x)+6f'(x)+12f''(x)+8f'''(x)=0$$ is a differential equation?

Comment: Why can't $f(x)-\sin{x}$ for example?  You can't assume $f$ is a polynomial.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I believe the question is looking for zeros, not assuming that the equation $f(x)+6f'(x)+12f''(x)+8f'''(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Comment: This was [asked before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1799748) and so far technically unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $g(x) = e^{x/2} f(x)$.  Then 
$$g'''(x) =  \dfrac{e^{x/2}}{8} \left(f(x) + 6 f'(x) + 12 f''(x) + 8 f'''(x)\right)$$
Now use Rolle's theorem.

Comment: How on earth did you come up with this?

Comment: @Sambo Look at the other thread linked in the comments above. It gives the motivation that helps achieve this result.

Comment: What I did was solve the differential equation $f + 6 f' + 12 f'' + 8 f''' = 0$, and notice that the solutions were polynomials times $e^{-x/2}$.